# ActiveRecord query with Rails 4

Tags: sql, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Could you help me with my problem.
I have parent table - subscriptions and each subscription can have different amount of versions (subscription_versions table).

Versions have it's own MRR and date.

I need display sum of all versions mrr on that period

So I have 2 subscription and 3 versions for each: {date: 1, mrr: 100}, {date: 2, mrr: 200}, {date: 3, mrr: 600}

So in that case it should be: 200 400 1200

I created query `@subscritoins.joins(:subscriptions_versions).select(SUM(mrr)).where('subscription_versions.date <= ?, date')`

but in that case it calculate sum and al previous versions, I need take only last version on that condition for sum

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding your conditions, but did you try, `@subscriptions.joins(:subscriptions_versions).where('subscription_versions.date <= ?, date').sum(:mrr)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@subscriptoions.joins(:subscription_versions).
                where('version = (SELECT MAX(version) FROM subscription_versions WHERE subscription_versions.subscription_id = subscriptions.id AND contract_effective_date <= ?)', el[:end_date]).
                sum(:mrr)
```